# What is the maximum number of questions I can ask every day?

Tags: support

I have asked three questions in the last 24 hours, and I feel embarrassed because I think I have made the Stack Exchange system busy.

I would like to know whether there is any restriction on the number of questions that a user can ask every day?
Is it 5 or 10 something (I am guessing)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering your reputation, there's effectively no limit to the number of questions you are allowed to ask per day. This information comes from the [Complete Rate Limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/284336) on Meta Stack Exchange.

> #### Asking
>
> - Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network
>
>   - Users limited by Anti-Recidivism System, one question per week
>   - Users limited from asking questions for 1 – 7 days based on the performance of their previous questions
> - Users with < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 60 seconds
> - Users with > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds

Please do take the time regardless of this to make certain your questions are of good quality and well-researched. Too many low-quality questions may not cause you to be blocked from asking but they may cause annoyance. So, ask away!

Comment: In addition to "annoyance," the moderation team is sometimes flagged automatically when a user has too many questions that get downvoted. Moreover, _consistently low quality questions over time_ is one of the predefined reasons for temporary suspension from the site. (This isn't common, but it has happened.)